# Can Sophisticated Malware, Spyware and Viruses Read Files?

Tags: windows-7, security, virus, anti-virus, malware

I've recently began encrypting my personal files using [veracrypt](https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/). I've got my resume, which, obviously contains personal information (name, address, phone number etc.) A little bit of reading [here](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit), would suggest that malware goes for the banking/credit card information, so it can read or capture data in some way.

**Question:**

If for example, my machine was infected with spyware/malware, can it read the data stored on my computer, i.e documents and pictures and send it to someone who might attempt to steal my information?

Comment: @1Fish_2Fish_RedFish_BlueFish - I created a encrypted container with veracrypt and dumped everything is there.

Comment: You are correct about VC, I store the passphrase in KeePass and everything is kept separate, if someone where to get the container, then that's all they have, no passphrase, nothing. They might as well delete the container because they aren't opening it. Could you elaborate of the PDF/Zip solution, why PDF?

Comment: @1Fish_2Fish_RedFish_BlueFish - I've done exactly that, so I guess I'm in good shape. Many thanks.

Comment: If malware can create a key, encrypt every file on ever drive it can see, then delete your key then yes malware can read every file the user has access to.  If the file is encrypted it would only have access when the user had access (I.e when its decrypted )

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Take these to facts together:

1) Windows security updates often state that they are fixing a vulnerability that could allow an attacker to **execute arbitrary code** on your computer.

2) One can write a program that reads all files on your computer and sends them over the Internet. This is not necessarily malware - it could be just a backup program.

Now, consider the above two points together. An attacker can exploit the vulnerability to execute a program that reads all your files and sends them to the attacker.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, sophisticated malware can definitely read files.  If you want to research more on the topic, Google "Data Exfiltration" - here is a [starting point](http://blog.trendmicro.com/trendlabs-security-intelligence/data-exfiltration-in-targeted-attacks/), which pretty much answers your question.